# burning subtitles onto mp4, such that they always show, and cannot be turned off

Tags: ffmpeg

I have successfully create a command line that allows subtitles to be displayed, I can see them when I select the track number in VLC. What I would like is to burn the subtitles such that they always show when the mp4 is played by any player, and not provide the option to be turned off. All i need is a clue to pursue. does ffmpeg have an option to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter to make *hardsubs* (burnt-in subtitles).

Assuming you have a subtitles file named `sub.srt`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "subtitles=sub.srt" output.mp4
```

Or if the subtitles are in `input.mkv`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "subtitles=input.mkv" output.mp4
```

Comment: I've added  "-disposition:s:0 default" option to the command but no improvements.

Comment: @Plazar99  "-disposition:s:0 default" has no effect because hardsubs are a part of the video itself. "-disposition:s:0 default" is only for softsubs. My examples make hardsubs.

Comment: can you give an example with -filter_complex?

Comment: @Plazar99 ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "subtitles=sub.srt" output.mp4

Comment: My input file is an mp4, not .mkv would this be the reason it's not working?

Comment: @Plazar99 You never showed any info about the inputs so I just have to keep guessing. As a result the answer has taken 9 extra days. Try `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=input.mp4" output.mp4`

Comment: the past  week I have been trying different permutations of the command options and filter from simplest suggestions. I haven't exhausted all the permutations yet. but I'm starting to conclude that the ffmpeg version on my target is missing something, because all the commands work fine on windows.  you have been very helpful, the problem is on my target build I need to trouble shoot that first. I will update everyone with my findings once I've fixed it.

Comment: @Plazar99 For next time, please always include your ffmpeg command and the complete log from the command. It will help you get answers much faster.

Comment: ffmpeg  -y -i "tmprender.mp4" -vf "subtitles=tmprender.mp4:force_style='Fontsize=20,PrimaryColour=&H0xB13186&,Alignment=0,MarginV=100,MarginL=100'" -c:v libx264 -c:s mov_text -c:a copy "output.mp4"

Comment: This is the last command I tried, it works on windows but not on android ffmpeg. given my deadline. I decided to move the file on a windows server and burn the subtitles there. Its a step that I'd like to eliminate. Note I have tried many permutations of this command. The ffmpeg on my android is from 2016 from writingminds

Comment: @Plazar99 Again, I need to see the complete log from the ffmpeg command to be able to tell you what is wrong. Otherwise I can only just provide guesses, such as perhaps your ffmpeg on Android was not configured with `--enable-libass` [as required by the subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).